# How to style mathjax properly on this case?

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I can`t style the way I want to.

This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
"Simplify $\\dfrac {{n^5} x {10n}} {2n^2}$"
```

This is the output:

[image]

The problem is the "x"

Comment: It's not an `x` but a multiplication sign, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign. Try `\times`.

Comment: thanks alot. it works perfect now.